# Check if all values in an array are equal but ignore null values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list of strings and nulls. Now I want to check if all strings in the list are the same and nulls should be ignored. So for instance

- `[null, "a", "a", null, "a"]` should evaluate to `true`, because all strings are equal
- `[null, "a", "a", null, "b"]` should evaluate to `false`, because there is "b" and "a"

There are other questions on SO that are concerned with finding duplicates or equal values, but none of them seem to consider `null` values.

I already thought about implementing this with

- a loop where I would save the first string and then compare to it in the later iterations
- a `filter` followed by `every`

However I was wondering if there is a better more intuitive way to do this.

Comment: Maybe `new Set(array.filter((value) => value !== null)).size <= 1`?

Comment: no need to iterate every, can exit early with some

Comment: @SebastianSimon Please submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Philipp [gog’s idea](/a/76481695/4642212) is even better.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I have seen his answer. Please submit yours as well, so I can accept it as an answer, if I decide that I like it more.

Comment: @0stone0 The question is close however it doesn't consider `null`s in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
set = new Set(yourArray)
set.delete(null)
if (set.size === 1)
   // unique
```

Answer (score 1):

> - a loop where I would save the first string and then compare to it in the later iterations
> - a filter followed by every

you can do it with an empty variable followed by every:

```
let j; // first non null value
const result = array.every((v,i,a) => v === null || v === a[j??=i]) && j != null;
```

*Edit:* OK, let's take this apart:

- `every((v,i,a) => v === null || ...)` check that every element is either `null` or ...
- so `v === a[j??=i]` is only executed when `v` is **not** `null`
- [j ??= i](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) is basically a shorthand for `j === null || j === undefined ? (j = i) : j` so `j` will adapt the first `i` where `v !== null`
- but our loop doesn't differentiate between `array.every((v,i,a) => v === null)` and `array.every((v,i,a) => v === a[j??=i])` so we also want to check that `v === a[j??=i]` was executed at least once by checking that the index `j` is not null anymore.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't read this code. What I like about this though is the fact that it has early stopping.

Comment: @Philipp I don't get what you mean with "can't read this code". As in *I don't understand how it works* or what?

Comment: I don't understand how it works. I understand that you are implementing the idea of `a loop where I would save the first string and then compare to it in the later iterations`. However I - for instance - don't understand what is the point of the `j != null`. In my head this is not necessary.